# get clicked element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want add class to clicked li and delete other li class

```
 <ul>
    <li onclick="s()"><span>خانه</span></li>
    <li onclick="s()"><span>سفارش</span></li>
    <li onclick="s()" class="selected"><span>آپلود</span></li>
    <li onclick="s()"><span>درباره ما</span></li>
    <li onclick="s()"><span>تنظیمات</span></li>
 </ul>
```

I can do it with jquery but now i want do this with javascript?

Comment: just to know you got the downvotes because you didn't show what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

Don't use inline click handlers. Instead, attach a handler from JavaScript.

```
 <ul id="myUL"> <!-- This is just for example, to make it easier to select -->
    <li><span>خانه</span></li>
    <li><span>سفارش</span></li>
    <li class="selected"><span>آپلود</span></li>
    <li><span>درباره ما</span></li>
    <li><span>تنظیمات</span></li>
 </ul>
```

Then, in JavaScript:

```
var myUL = document.querySelector('#myUL');
// Attach one event listener on the parent, instead of one for each element.
// It's more performant and will work with dynamically added entries!
myUL.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Here, event.target is the actual event clicked.
    // Remove class from selected one.
    document.querySelector('#myUL .selected').classList.remove('selected');
    // And add it to the current one
    event.target.classList.add('selected');
});
```

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2eh2xm16/)**

Answer (score 1):

This is a **quick fix** and this way is not recommended. But in your case, you need to use this way:

```
function s (which) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".clicked")[0].classList.remove("selected");
    which.classList.add("selected");
}
```

And change the call this way:

```
 <ul>
    <li onclick="s(this)"><span>خانه</span></li>
    <li onclick="s(this)"><span>سفارش</span></li>
    <li onclick="s(this)" class="selected"><span>آپلود</span></li>
    <li onclick="s(this)"><span>درباره ما</span></li>
    <li onclick="s(this)"><span>تنظیمات</span></li>
 </ul>
```

---

The right way is to use `eventListeners` and bind the events to an ID.

```
var list = document.querySelector('#menu');
list.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    list.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove('selected');
    event.target.classList.add('selected');
});
```

And add the ID to the `<ul>`:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>خانه</li>
    <li>سفارش</li>
    <li class="selected">آپلود</li>
    <li>درباره ما</li>
    <li>تنظیمات</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: your answer is correct but you should not support bad practicing

Comment: `querySelectorAll(...)[0]`? Inline click handlers? Frankly, I expect more from a 40k+ user.

Comment: Sorry guys... It was a quick fix.

Comment: don't forget to add the id to the ul element

Comment: @MadaraUchiha... Have a look!

Comment: the first solution doesn't work. i want do it with onclick for training

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy Train on best practices, not on bad ones. Inline onclick handlers are *bad practice*, they shouldn't be used.